# Why does PHP substr() change ASCII carriage return byte?

Tags: php, binary-data, substr

I was going to use a long string to manipulate a large number of bit flags, keeping the result string in Redis. However, stumbled upon a php bug (?). A byte that contains bits `00001101` read using `substr()` returns an unexpected value:

```
$bin = 0b00001101;  // 13 - ASCII Carriage return
$c = substr($bin, 0, 1);    // read this character
printf("Expectation: 00001101, reality: %08b\n", $c); // 00000001
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/CCgxm4)

Is the assumption that `substr()` is binary-safe wrong? Also tried `mb_substr()`, setting encoding to `8bit` with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting `$bin` to an **integer** `13`

Using `substr()` against `$bin` is casting `$bin` to a **string** (`"13"`)

You're reading the first character of that string (`"1"`)

Using `printf()` with `%b`, you're explicitly casting that string back to an integer `1`

> the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a binary number.

**EDIT**

This code should give the result that you're expecting

```
$bin = 0b00001101;  // 13 - ASCII Carriage return
$c = substr(chr($bin), 0, 1);    // read this character
printf("Expectation: 00001101, reality: %08b\n", ord($c)); // 00001101
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably I created a bad example/isolation of the problem. Originally I have a longer binary string, reading a particular byte from it. Will rewrite the example.

Comment: True, now I get it. Thanks again!